# Analyzing core file of shared object

Tags: linux, debugging, shared-libraries

**Tests :**

**[1]** creating divide of 0 in **executable** hat was compiled with optimization (O2) and debugging symbols , thus a core was generated.

**[2]** creating divide of 0 in **shared object** hat was compiled with optimization (O2) and debugging symbols , thus a core was generated.

**Results:**

**[First]** analysing the core generated by [1] was succeeded and an exact location of the crush could be seen in GDB/Totalview.

**[Second]** analysing the core generated by [2] was NOT succeeded and a hex numeric location was the output of the crush.

can someone tell how can i get [2] to succeed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it , 
i was opening the core file like this :

1. gdb core core-file-name
2. file location-of-binary

then the binary symbols was loaded, BUT Not any shared objects !!!!!

going this way :

1. gdb -c core-file-name location-of-binary

this caused binary symbols to be loaded BUT ALSO shared objects symbols to be loaded as well !!!

thanks for the help.

Comment: Another note: Dont forget , the shared objects must be at the same location they were in the machine that produced the core.

Answer (score 1):

Check with ldd  that your shared object can be found.

If not, try with shell variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to set its path and try again `gdb <executable> core`.

Another option is to edit config `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run ldconfig.

Comment: tried to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the shared object path, didnt work... btw... am i supposed to see the library with ldd ? cause i cant see it when i ldd on my exec....

Comment: I thought your exec is linked against this shared library. In this case you should see its name with ldd. But you're probably not and must be loading it with dlopen then?

Comment: It still should work... if you're using relative path for loading the library, make sure you run it directory where the relative path is valid. Check also for errors after running `gdb exec core`, it will give you the hint of what's wrong.

Comment: i've tried gdb exec core and noticed :

"Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted"

Comment: i've noticed this errors while trying to debug the core with TotalView: 

ERROR: Failed, reading struct r_debug address=0xffffffff
Error getting dynamic loader base address

Comment: Could you edit your question adding whole gdb output. "program terminated..." is ok, I'm not sure about the second error. Is your shared object compiled with -fPIC option?