# analysis of core file

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, redhat

I'm using Linux redhat 3, can someone explain how is that possible that i am able to analyze 
with gdb , a core dump generated in Linux redhat 5 ?

not that i complaint :) but i need to be sure this will always work...  ?

EDIT: the shared libraries are the same version, so no worries about that, they are placed in a shaerd storage so it can be accessed from both linux 5 and linux 3.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience analysing core file, generated on other system, do not work, because standard library (and other libraries your program probably use) typically will be different, so addresses of the functions are different, so you cannot even get a sensible backtrace.

Don't do it, because even if it works sometimes, you cannot rely on it.

Comment: ok thanks , but do you have an explanation why shouldnt i rely on it ? i add : assuming the shared libraries ofcourse are the same versions

Comment: You cannot assume same versions for shared libraries because kernel is different, therefore `glibc` is different, and I'm sure the whole bunch of other libraries are different as well.

Comment: There are many scenarios where using heterogeneous systems is unavoidable - embedded systems is a perfect example.  Your point is a valid caveat, but Anil below has a solution that answers the question as asked.

Comment: @Greg I see no reason why did you downvote the correct answer

Comment: I feel that Anil has actually tried to answer the question as asked, you caveats are important - it is difficult and could be problematic - but not impossible, but don't really constitute an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try following commands of GDB to open a core file

```
gdb
 (gdb) exec-file <executable address>
 (gdb) set solib-absolute-prefix <path to shared library>
 (gdb) core-file <path to core file>
```

The reason why you can't rely on it is because every process used libc or system shared library,which will definitely has changes from Red hat 3 to red hat 5.So all the instruction address and number of instruction in native function will be diff,and there where debugger gets goofed up,and possibly can show you wrong data to analyze. So its always good to analyze the core on the same platform or if you can copy all the required shared library to other machine and set the path through set solib-absolute-prefix.

Comment: Thank-you! splitting core-load up from the command-line was exactly the trick I needed to get solib-absolute-prefix working.  Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

You can always run `gdb -c /path/to/corefile /path/to/program_that_crashed`. However, if program_that_crashed has no debug infos (i.e. was not compiled *and* linked with the `-g` gcc/ld flag) the coredump is not that useful unless you're a hard-core debugging expert ;-)

Note that the generation of corefiles can be disabled (and it's very likely that it is disabled by default on most distros). See `man ulimit`. Call `ulimit -c` to see the limit of core files, "0" means disabled. Try `ulimit -c unlimited` in this case. If a size limit is imposed the coredump will not exceed the limit size, thus maybe cutting off valuable information.

Also, the path where a coredump is generated depends on /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern. Use `cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to query the current pattern. It's actually a path, and if it doesn't start with `/` then the file will be generated in the current working directory of the process. And if `cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid` returns "1" then the coredump will have the file PID of the crashed process as file extension. You can also set both value, e.g. `echo -n /tmp/core > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` will force all coredumps to be generated in /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question as:

> how is it possible that I am able to
>   analyse a core that was produced under
>   one version of an OS under another
>   version of that OS?

Just because you are lucky (even that is questionable). There are a lot of things that can go wrong by trying to do so:

- the tool chains `gcc`, `gdb` etc will
  be of different versions
- the shared libraries will be of
  different versions

so no, you shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: ok thanks , but do you have an explanation why shouldnt i rely on it ? i add : assuming the shared libraries ofcourse are the same versions

Answer (score -1):

You have asked similar question and accepted an answer, ofcourse by yourself here : [Analyzing core file of shared object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502340/analyzing-core-file-of-shared-object)

Once you load the core file you can get the stack trace and get the last function call and check the code for the reason of crash.

There is a small tutorial [here](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/linux/gdb-gnu-debugger-intro.php) to get started with.

EDIT:

Assuming you want to know how to analyse core file using gdb on linux as your question is little unclear.

Comment: this is by no doubt not any duplicate question to what you have attached.

Comment: Well you could have written that a little more clearly. I can see people are trying to guess what your actual question is :).